# AEM File upload content 404

Tags: html, image, adobe, aem

I'm developing a basic image component with a file upload.
My dialog works but the file won't show up in my component. It gives me a 404 even though the content is in the JCR.

My dialog: http://pastebin.com/u8VLKucv

My component:

```
<div data-sly-use.carousel="carousel.js">
    <img src="${carousel.image.src}"/>
</div>
```

Carousel.js:

```
'use strict';

use(['/libs/wcm/foundation/components/utils/Image.js'], function(Image) {
    var carousel = {};

    carousel.image = new Image(granite.resource);

    return carousel;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sling:resourceSuperType had to be set to parbase